# Margin-left css not working

Tags: css, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am using jquery date picker,i added date picker to my jsp page,and i want to move it left,but it doesn't work..
In my jsp page i have

```
<div id="datepicker" class="datepicker">
        <script>
        $("#datepicker").datepicker();
        </script>
        </div>
```

and in my css file i have

```
.datepicker{

        margin-top:20px;
        margin-left:600px;
        position: fixed;

}
```

but the element is always on top left corner..Does someone have solution for this?I always used margin-top and margin-left when i wanted to position element,and it always worked..Thanks in advance!

Comment: that's because you have `position: fixed;` set so it will put it in the top left corner because those are the default values (0) for `top` and `left`. If you are going to position it like this then set the `top` and `left` to the values you want.

Comment: i put `top:20px` and `left:600px`,but it is the same..as i understood,margin-left and margin-top move that element to the left and to the bottom for that number of pixels,and that's what i need..i don't know whats the difference between top and left and margin-top and margin-left..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm having trouble getting the datepicker function to run on codepen, but the CSS formatting part is working just fine: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OWdXKL

```
<style>
  .datepicker{
        margin-top:20px;
        margin-left:600px;
        position: fixed;
};
</style>

<div id="datepicker" class="datepicker">this div is 600 px from the left; 20 px from the top</div>

<script>
  $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
</script>
```

My guess would be that there is something somewhere else in your stylesheet that is overriding the margins defined in the snip you provided.

Comment: It works now,after i cleaned up project in eclipse and erased history...thanks anyway!